# how to check time difference of two fields that use time pickers

Tags: javascript, timepicker

I have two time pickers and I need to check if the time selected from start to end is within a correct range, i got the values difference checked, but the values returned is NaN. Time shown is as 8:00 PM to 10:00 PM etc.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
<label>Service Start</label>
<input class="form-control timepicker1"  type="text" id="start_time" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<label>Service End</label>
<input class="form-control timepicker1"  type="text" id="end_time" />
</div>
```

Comment: A utility library like [moment](https://momentjs.com/) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) can help you compare the two dates. Look at the feature set in both libraries before you make a decision. Moment is a larger library that does more, if you don't need the extras moment includes date-fns will be better for performance.

Comment: Well how did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Likely not the best since handling times with AM and PM you need to do some more work, also you need to check if first_time < second_time.
What you do is convert hh:mm:ss in seconds than input seconds in new Date() and can get different outputs.
But it should give you an idea how it can be done. moment.js can make things a lot easier

```js
var hm_1 = '09:00 PM';   
var hm_2 = '12:00 PM';
var a = hm_1.split(/:| /); // split at : and " "
var b = hm_2.split(/:| /);
// convert hours and minutes into seconds
var sec_1 = a[0] * 60 * 60 + a[1] * 60; 
var sec_2 = b[0] * 60 * 60 + b[1] * 60; 
console.log("convert", hm_1, "and", hm_2, "in", "seconds", sec_1, sec_2);
var date = new Date();
var date = new Date((sec_2 - sec_1) * 1000); //use js new Date () can take s/h/... as input
var hh = date.getUTCHours();  //get hours
var mm = date.getUTCMinutes(); //get minutes
if (hh < 10) {hh = "0"+hh;}
if (mm < 10) {mm = "0"+mm;}
// convert to hh:mm (its a 24h format)
var timeString = hh+":"+mm;
console.log("result", timeString)
```